# Python Sound Device Recording

Tags: python, audio, python-sounddevice

I am trying to create a .wav file by recording from a USB microphone connected to my computer. I am trying to accomplish this using Python. I keep seeing the following example (or something similar) to record, but I am having trouble understanding where the audio device is specified here? If there are multiple microphones, which one would it be recording from? Thanks!

```
duration = 10  # seconds
myrecording = sd.rec(duration * fs, samplerate=fs, channels=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing [the documentation for `sounddevice`](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.7/#device-selection):

> Use `sounddevice.query_devices()` or `python -m sounddevice` to get a list of supported devices.

> You can use the corresponding device ID to select a desired device by assigning to `sounddevice.default.device` or by passing it as device argument to `sounddevice.play()`, `sounddevice.Stream()` etc.

> Instead of the numerical device ID, you can also use a space-separated list of case-insensitive substrings of the device name.

IOW,

```
myrecording = sounddevice.rec(
    duration * fs,
    samplerate=fs,
    channels=2,
    device="USB",
)
```

could do if your microphone shows up as e.g. "USB Audio Device".

You can see `device` [here](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.7/#sounddevice.InputStream) in the docs for `InputStream`; [`sounddevice.rec()`](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.7/#sounddevice.rec)'s docs refer to that for the other `**kwargs`.